# Зачем в этой программе add dx,2

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ассемблер TASM.Программа просит ввести имя и затем выводит его в центре экрана.
Для чего в программе команда add dx,2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно всего лишь посмотреть описание десятой (0ah,  буферизованный ввод строки) функции 21h прерывания и увидеть, что перед введённым текстом хранятся два служебных байта:

```
 при выходе буфер заполнен данными следующим образом:
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+- - -
    ¦max¦len¦ T   E   X   T   0dH   LEN - действительная длина данных
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+ -  -  без завершающего CR (здесь - 04H).
```